# Retrieve data from DE before post method

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, landing-page

I am working on Marketing cloud project where I need to take input from customer and store in Data Extension and redirect them to the welcome page. I have done this but now the requirement is changed. 
Now input fields are picklist and second picklist values are depend on first one. So we have to call server before submitting button to return the data required for second picklist.

Do anyone have worked on such scenario?? Any suggestions will be really appreciable

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Store value of the first Picklist and call Form Action Submit from JavaScript as soon as the value in that Picklist field changes, do a Lookup. and reload the page. I can think of only this solution as AJAX won't work with Cloud Pages.

Comment: Thanks Ankit for your reply!! but when the page will be reloaded then value of first picklist get reset again. I haven't done anything like this before. IF you have any idea to do this then it would be really helpful for me..